# Firebase: How does it know what account my OAuth token is associated with?

Tags: ios, firebase, oauth, firebase-authentication

I'm about to build an iPad app that uses OAuth 2.0 using this cocoapod: https://github.com/OAuthSwift/OAuthSwift. I'm looking through this firebase tutorial (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/custom-auth) but, I'm a little confused.

Given I have this code:

```
oauthswift = OAuth2Swift(
    consumerKey:    "********",
    consumerSecret: "********",
    authorizeUrl:   "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize",
    responseType:   "token"
)
let handle = oauthswift.authorize(
    withCallbackURL: URL(string: "oauth-swift://oauth-callback/instagram")!,
    scope: "likes+comments", state:"INSTAGRAM",
    success: { credential, response, parameters in
      print(credential.oauth_token)
      FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withCustomToken: credential.oauth_token ?? "") { (user, error) in
        // ...
      }

    },
    failure: { error in
      print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
)
```

How would firebase know what account that token is associated with if the token is random and different for each device? I don't know how to associate that token to an account. Like if I signed in to instagram with username `cool@example.com` and password `blah123` and the oauth_token was `123abc` how would I know that `123abc` was connected to `cool@example.com` in my firebase account if `123abc` was random?

I feel like I'm misunderstanding one of the concepts.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the custom token from the Instagram access token server-side using the Firebase SDK's. You then need to request this from the server via the client and `signIn withCustomToken:` using the token in the response.

Comment: So I should set the `withCallbackURL` to `myserver.com/something` and on my server create a custom token, then in the `success` callback, I'm supposed to make another request to my server to fetch this custom token using the oauth_token returned by instagram?

Comment: You need to create a custom, signed JWT token using either Firebase Admin SDK or yourself on server-side and pass that to `FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withCustomToken: ` inside your app. Custom JWT will contain user's `uid` (either Instagram's or your internal one), which is what will uniquely identify that user to Firebase (and allow you cross-reference between different platforms). This link describes it fairly well: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens